# Compound index with lodash/underscore

Tags: javascript, indexing, underscore.js, lodash, compound-index

When working with data from database, we often get arrays of stuff that, due to database constraints, can be (uniquely) indexed by compound indices. However, [`indexBy`](https://lodash.com/docs#indexBy) does not seem to work for compound indices, or does it?

Given an array `x` with objects that have properties `a` and `b`, I want to have a dictionary of dictionaries that contain all objects of `x`, indexed by `a` and `b`, respectively. For example:

[Fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/3rb3gvrg/2/).

```
var x = [
    {
        a: 1,
        b: 11,
        c: 101
    },
    {
        a: 2,
        b: 11,
        c: 101
    },
    {
        a: 1,
        b: 11,
        c: 102
    },
    {
        a: 1,
        b: 14,
        c: 102
    },
];

// index x by a, then by b, then by c    
var byABC = _.compoundIndexBy(x, ['a', 'b', 'c']);

// there are two items in `x` with a = 1 and b = 11
console.assert(_.size(byABC[1][11]) == 2, 'Something went wrong...');

// display result
console.log(byABC);
```

`byABC` now looks like this:

```
{
    1: {
        11: {
            101: {
                a: 1,
                b: 11,
                c: 101
            },
            102: {
                a: 1,
                b: 11,
                c: 102
            }
        },
        14: {
            102: {
                a: 1,
                b: 14,
                c: 102
            }
        },
    }
    2: {
        11:{
            101: {
                a: 2,
                b: 11,
                c: 101
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[This Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3rb3gvrg/2/) demonstrates the `compoundexIndexBy` function. Is my work in vain (because [Lo-Dash](https://lodash.com) actually does support compound indices), or can it at least be improved?

Comment: Can you clarify by "printing" the desired result object (`byABC`)?

Comment: @gadr90 Done. I wrote more code to basically simulate a database composite index on my client-side cached data, which is necessary to make this actually useful and manageable. I.e. I also added methods to add and remove data from this "index data structure".

Answer (score 1):

You can create a mixin that recursively groups/indexes your objects:

```
_.mixin({
    compoundIndexBy: function(lst, iteratees, context) { 
        if (iteratees.length === 1) 
            return _.indexBy(lst, iteratees[0], context);

        var grouped = _.groupBy(lst, iteratees[0], context);

        _.each(grouped, function(sublst, k) {
            grouped[k] = _.compoundIndexBy(sublst, _.rest(iteratees), context);
        });

        return grouped;
    }
});

console.dir(_.compoundIndexBy(x, ['a', 'b', 'c']));
```

If you prefer a list of objects matching the given indexes (in case of non unique paths, for example):

```
_.mixin({
    compoundGroupBy: function(lst, iteratees, context) {
        var grouped = _.groupBy(lst, iteratees[0], context);

        if (iteratees.length === 1) 
            return grouped;

        _.each(grouped, function(sublst, k) {
            grouped[k] = _.compoundGroupBy(sublst, _.rest(iteratees), context);
        });

        return grouped;
    }
});
console.dir(_.compoundGroupBy(x, ['a', 'b', 'c']));
```

And a demo http://jsfiddle.net/nikoshr/8w4n31vb/

Comment: Recursion does seems the best option here. You beat me to it :)